# Is there a centralized open source code repository for C#?

Tags: c#, open-source, repository

For Perl, there is cpan.org, where I can lookup and reuse any previously built package in my own code.

Is there a similar open source code repository for C#?

---

Edit: Thanks all.  I also just found code.google.com.

Comment: i suggested Google Code as well. It's a bit thin though. You'll want to look at CodePlex and SourceForge first. Those have been around for years and host many hundreds of useful projects between them.

Answer (score 9):

http://www.codeplex.com/ for starters. That's the most "official" one. But you'll find numerous other resources such as [sourceforge.net](http://sourceforge.net) and [CodeProject.com](http://CodeProject.com)

[Google Code](http://code.google.com/apis/base/samples/csharp/csharp-sample.html) also has a C# section

Comment: CodePlex has far more C# projects then any other site.

Comment: RIP CodePlex  :(

Answer (score 4):

I think your what your looking for is [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/).

[Wikipedia Entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodePlex):

> CodePlex is an open source project hosting website from Microsoft. It allows shared development of open source software. Its features include wiki pages, source control based on Team Foundation Server but accessible using Subversion, discussion forums, issue tracking, project tagging, RSS support, statistics, and releases.
>   While Codeplex encompasses a wide variety of projects, including SQL, WPF and Windows Forms-related projects, major activities center around the .NET framework, including ASP.NET, and Microsoft's intranet collaboration server, SharePoint. The most prominent and used project that was born inside CodePlex, the AJAX Control Toolkit is a joint project between the community and Microsoft.

Answer (score 3):

codeplex - not really 100% match to your need but has got lots of goodies

also codeproject

Comment: or github or other sites that google suggest as similar sites